# Rspec and capybara selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I want to assert if certain select has certain value and not text. This works if I assert by text :

```
it 'should be true' do
   should have_select("country", :selected => 'Brazil')
end
```

My select html is like this :

```
<select name="user[country]" id="country">
  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
 ...
</select>
```

I want to assert does page have select with selected value, how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not believe there is a built-in matcher for checking the select list by value.

You can however, get the select list's value (ie selected option's value) by using the `value` method:

```
find(:css, 'select#country').value
```

You could compare this to the expected value, using the expect syntax:

```
expect( find(:css, 'select#country').value ).to eq('BR')
```

Or using the should syntax:

```
find(:css, 'select#country').value.should == 'BR'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you prefer to stay away from CSS selectors:

```
find_field("country").value.must_equal "BR"
```

This assumes you name the label for this field `country`.

Answer (score -1):

In newer versions of RSpec and Capybara you can use `have_select`.

```
expect(page).to have_select("Time of day", text: "8:30 AM")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to only test that "8:30 AM" is available as an option in the dropdown, not that it is the selected option.